# git help is from wrong version of git

Tags: git

I want to see the "git help rebase" screen from git 1.7.6.  I'm on Ubuntu. Here's what I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
cd git
git checkout v1.7.6
git clean -xfd
make
make install
```

This puts a "git" binary into my ~/bin directory, and if I run ~/bin/git --version it says:  "git version 1.7.6".

But if I run "~/bin/git help rebase" and scroll to the very bottom of the help screen it says "Git 2.7.4".

How can I get a "git help" screen that matches the git version I'm running?

Comment: you need `make doc`

Comment: I think it's `make install-man install-html`

Comment: Trying these now.  Just realized I need to do this:  "apt-get install asciidoc"

Man-a-war!  "After this operation, 1,297 MB of additional disk space will be used."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!   In the end this did it:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git.git
cd git
git checkout v1.7.6
git clean -xfd
make
make install

# And now to build & install man pages:
apt-get install asciidoc
make man
make install-doc
```

It installed them here:

```
install -d -m 755 /home/gsylvie/share/man/man1
install -d -m 755 /home/gsylvie/share/man/man5
install -d -m 755 /home/gsylvie/share/man/man7
```

And now "git help rebase" says "Git 1.7.6" at the bottom.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Could be `rehash -d git`.

If `command -v git` doesn't show the path where you installed 1.7.6, then you may be running the old executable bashed on the shell's cached record of "where to find git".  The above command deletes that information, and the next time you refer to the *git* command, it will search the `PATH` again to locate it.